# Did any poets or authors say that youth came after age before Bob Dylan?

Tags: poetry, song-lyrics, bob-dylan

In the song "My Back Pages" Bob Dylan famously inverted the usual chronological assumption of aging by poetically saying

> I was so much older then,
> I'm younger than that now.

This concept was later copied by other artists, for instance Eric Burdon of The Animals in "When I Was Young"

> I was so much older then, when I was young.

What I would like to know is: Was Bob Dylan the first artist, poet, or author to invert the concept of aging in this way? Are there examples from an older poem, play, novel, or other work with a similar implication that old age or a precocious maturity came before youth? I am not asking for a "biological clock running backwards" example like Mork from Ork or a "time stream running backwards" example like Merlin in T. H. White's *The Sword in the Stone*, but of a more natural change of viewpoint or maturity in the sense that both Bob Dylan and Eric Burdon mean it.

Comment: You maybe want to narrow down your question. Otherwise, descriptions comparing senility with infancy would fit, as in Shakespeares "Seven Ages of Man" speech:

*... and his big manly voice, //
Turning again toward childish treble, pipes //
And whistles in his sound. Last scene of all, //
That ends this strange eventful history, //
Is second childishness and mere oblivion, //
Sans teeth, sans eyes, sans taste, sans everything.*

Comment: @PeterShor You can take that back all the way to [Solon](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0479%3Avolume%3D1%3Atext%3D5%3Asection%3D2) (CTRL+F "ages of man"), though Solon he doesn't mention reverting back to childishness in that poem.